# Incorrect string value error when trying to insert in MySQL table

Tags: mysql, csv

I'm trying to import a CSV file using MySQL workbench. It's a very old file converted to CSV using a PEARL script from an old FoxPro database.

I'm also getting an error:

```
Error Code: 1366. Incorrect string value: '\xDA400\xDA6...' for column 'KOD_P' at row 481158.
```

I suspect it has something to do with the encoding type. Currently I'm using `text` as the datatype and `utf8mb4 - default collation` as the Collation.

I'm pretty much stuck at this point. Any nudging in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try solutions written in answer for this question(check table encoding, column encoding etc.):

[using MySQL workbench to insert Arabic characters to the MySQL database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8771563/using-mysql-workbench-to-insert-arabic-characters-to-the-mysql-database)